# Not able retrieve NumberLong data from MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am not able to retrieve data from DB. I am using below query

```
db.getCollection('Emp_Data').find({"updatedDateTime":  {"$gte": {"$numberLong": "1671979860000"}}});
```

and I have data like this in my DB

```
"updatedDateTime" : NumberLong(1672059880000),
"createdDateTime" : NumberLong(1671695703836),
```

Please help.

```
db.getCollection('Emp_Data').find({"updatedDateTime":  {"$gte": {"$numberLong": "1671979860000"}}});
```

I tried above query, is it right or wrong, If wrong please help.

Comment: Did you try `{$gte: NumberLong("1671979860000")}` or `{$gte: Long("1671979860000")}`?